# Reduce video size

Tags: audio, video, media-files

I want to transfer video files over the internet. I intend to reduce a video size of 100x MB to below 10 MB. I tried some apps, but they reduce the size down to 10x MB, *not* below 10 MB. Also, their video qualities are *not* acceptable.

Is there is any app that can produce a video of less than 10 MB with high quality?

### UPDATE

My videos are around `5` minutes long. On a desktop computer, I use [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr) software with these settings to produce an acceptable output:

- Dimension `360` width by `640` height
- RF quality `33`
- FPS `15`
- Video codec H.264 (x264)
- Audio codec AAC stereo with `24` bitrate.

With the above settings, for example, a 700 MB video would become 7 MB.

I don't know how to set these values by any Android app. Is there any app for it? I tried [YouCut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.camerasideas.trimmer), but I couldn't find any such settings.

Comment: IIRC Handbrake uses FFMPeg. So maybe an app using a similar approach would be worth a try. [Video Transcoder](https://f-droid.org/packages/protect.videoeditor/) wasn't updated for more than a year, but going by the screenshots it allows you to specify values like you listed above.

Comment: @Izzy I tried *Video Transcoder*. I'm glad, looks like what I want =)

Comment: Glad to read! Made it an answer then so you can accept it and others can see the solution. Btw, when explicitly looking for an app, Android.SE is *not* the recommended place, see [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) (hint:we've got a specialized sister site for that). Usually, questions explicitly asking for apps are closed here; we counted it as "how can I" this time (answers recommending an app are OT, just explicitly asking for is not). // Enjoy your solution! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Video Transcoder](https://f-droid.org/packages/protect.videoeditor/)** seems to be what you are looking for:

- transcodes videos
- can reduce file size by manually adjusting parameters, as you are used to by Handbrake
- "size-reduced" videos have acceptable quality, again as you are used to by Handbrake

[image]
[image]
<sup>*Video Transcoder* (source: F-Droid)</sup>

While the app is also [available from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=protect.videoeditor), I recommend using F-Droid whenever possible: better privacy, and the only "store" where (until now) no malware was found ever.